# ADFS - Restrict to AD Group

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I just implemented an ADFS server to connect a third-party chat tool with our Active Directory via SAML 2.0.

Everything works fine so far but there's a little problem: As soon as a user logs in, the chat tool creates an account for him automatically. That's a problem because every account causes fees.

Is there any way to restrict the ADFS usage to an AD Group?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be done by adding a so-called *Issuance Authorization Rule*.

Step-by-step:

- Open AD FS Management Center
- Expand *Trust Relationsships*
- Select *Relying Party Trusts*
- Right click the required trust
- Click *Edit Claim Rules*
- Goto the *Issuance Authorization Rules* tab
- Delete the default *Permit Access To All Users* rule
- Click *Add Rule*
- Select *Permit or Deny Users Based on an Incoming Claim*
- Incoming Claim Type, select *Group SID*
- Click *Browse* at *Incoming claim value*
- Select the required group
- You're done